# Load search result php url in div on same page

Tags: javascript, php

I have search results and am displaying them in div on left of page. When user clicks on the a particular result (which is a link), it needs to open on the right of the page, without refreshing the page or moving to a new page. How does one do this?

```
    //get rows
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ ?>
        <div class="post_list">
        <?php
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                $postID = $row['id'];
        ?>
            <div class="list_item"><a href="file/file.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><h2><?php echo $row["title"] ?></h2></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have an onclick listeners on each `<a>` which will take your `file/file.php?id=` as input to an ajax call to fetch the contents at  file/file.php?id=.

I am not sure how familiar you are with Javascript, if you know it very well then you'll undersntand what I said above, if you don't then please find documentation about **AJAX** [some ajax documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

You might also want to find documentation on stuff like **innerHTML** [dom manipulation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Thanks nada that works! Only problem now is no matter what link I click the same id loads..

Comment: @ian  this is where now you have to look at the id you passed. Doing the ajax call via file.pho?id=someid means you are doing I believe a GET request so you'll get the value in PHP with something like $id = $_GET['id'];